# How to do running total of math calculation in IronPython

Tags: c#, python, math

I'm using IronPython in a C# app to calculate expressions. The user would input an expression like

```
A + B + C
```

I then execute a python script to do the calculation:

```
def main():
  return (A + B + C)
main()
```

How can I generate a running total that shows me the values as the calculation is performed? So for these inputs:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
```

I want this output:

```
A: 1
B: 3
C: 6
```

Currently I'm using regular expressions to extract the components and try to manually perform the calculation step by step, but it gets messed up when using parenthesis or when operator precedence causes expression to start calculating at another point, e.g. A + B + C * D / E

I think operator overloading would be the way to go. I know how to do this in C#, but python is still pretty new to me. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got a basic solution going: wrap values in an object (`MagicNumber`) which overloads the arithmetic operators.

```
RunningTotal = {}

class MagicNumber(object):

  def  __init__(self, name, value):
    self.name = str(name)
    if isinstance(value, MagicNumber):
      value = value.value
    self.value = float(value)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.value)

  def __add__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, MagicNumber):
      other = MagicNumber('literal', float(other))
    result = MagicNumber(self.name, self.value + other.value)
    RunningTotal[other.name] = result.value
    return result

  def __radd__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, MagicNumber):
      other = MagicNumber('literal', float(other))
    result = MagicNumber(self.name, other.value + self.value)
    RunningTotal[self.name] = result.value
    return result
```

So when you use it like this:

```
A = MagicNumber('A', 1)
B = MagicNumber('B', 2)
C = MagicNumber('C', 3)

result = A + B + C
```

You get these values in RunningTotal dictionary:

```
B: 3
C: 6
```

You can also overload the other operators (sub, mul, div, etc including their reverse counterparts). See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for possible overloads.